# Getting String from a textfield inside webpage iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, html

I'd like to get the content in a textfield (with an assigned ID) on a webpage and pass it into a NSString. 
Is there a way to load it instantly without taking every html source?
Thanks in advance.
P.S. I use objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute javascript using the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method on `UIWebView` in order to get the value of the textfield.  For example, if its ID is `foo`, you can write:

```
NSString *js = @"document.getElementById('foo').value";
NSString *value = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```